# mdDataTable repeats data when refreshed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using mdDataTable to display an ordinary tabular list of data.  When the code first initializes and loads the data table it contains the 5 rows returned by the web service call show below.   Everything appears as it should.

When the web service is called later to refresh the the data it returns the 5 rows that are expected and the array is assigned to the value named 'logAnalysis'.

The problem is that the data table appends the 5 new rows to the display and leaves the 5 original rows.

When I inspect the 'logAnalysis' value there is any array of 5 rows as expected.
It is as if the data table takes whatever values are placed into the array and appends them to an internal array then display the internal array.

To me, this behavior makes no sense.  What am I missing?

Template HTML:

```
<mdt-table>
<mdt-header-row>
    <mdt-column align-rule="left">Name</mdt-column>
    <mdt-column align-rule="right">Log Count</mdt-column>
    <mdt-column align-rule="right">Error Count</mdt-column>
    <mdt-column align-rule="right">File Size</mdt-column>
    <mdt-column align-rule="right">Time of Last Error</mdt-column>
</mdt-header-row>
<mdt-row ng-repeat="item in vm.logAnalysis">
    <mdt-cell>{{item.name}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{item.logCount}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{item.errorCount}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{item.fileSize}}</mdt-cell>
    <mdt-cell>{{item.timeOfLastError | date : 'medium' }}</mdt-cell>
</mdt-row>
</mdt-table>
```

Controller Javascript:

```
        $http.get('api/servicelog/counts').then(function (response) {
            vm.logAnalysis = response.data;
        });
```

Thank you in advance,
Jim

Comment: try  $http.get('api/servicelog/counts').then(function (response) {
            vm.logAnalysis = []; vm.logAnalysis = response.data;
        });

Comment: @Sajeetharan - thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it, but it did not help.  Previously I had tried setting vm.logAnalysis before making the api call.  Of course, that did not work either.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: I am working on it...

Comment: unable to get Angular-Material working at all in plunker.  :-(

Comment: can you modify this with your data https://plnkr.co/edit/bTSGzIIN5UpAGAKBjadD?p=preview